# Adding to a finite set of options; an API breaking change?

Tags: rest, api, api-design, json

Take an HTTP API endpoint which spits out the following response model:

```
{
    "type": "Dog",
    "name": "Jessi",
    ...
}
```

The `type` field has been described in the documentation as being one of `Dog`, `Cat`or `Fish`.

Would adding a new option,say `Rat`, be considered a breaking API change?

Is adding an option to a finite list (which a developer may switch on) considered an extension or a modifications to an API?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If the documentation described this field as being one of Dog, Cat, or Fish, then yes, adding another type changes the interface in a backwards-incompatible way. It is entirely conceivable that a consumer of your API has written specific code to deal with dogs and cats differently than with fish. Given an unknown type, that consumer wouldn't know what to do with your response. But this depends very much on what these placeholder types “Cat” and “Fish” represent in your actual problem domain…

If changes to the list of possible types is frequent, or if the list is not finite, then documenting this as such is sensible. Depending on your use cases, it might be good to expose a list of all possible types as an endpoint in your API – that way it's clear you can add or remove types without having to update the API version. However, the more dynamic your types are, the harder it becomes for API consumers to do something type-specific. Whether extensibility or ease of use is more important depends on your use cases and your problem domain.

Comment: Fantastic answer - thanks. What if the documentation detailed the options in some table titled with "the following table describes the animals *currently supported* by the API." Does this not indicate that the options could be expanded upon?

Comment: @davenewza That's probably a good idea but I would be more explicit. Don't just *indicate* what you mean – say it directly! I'd try to set clear expectations and offer a *stability guarantee* in the docs for that endpoint, something like: “The following table lists the currently supported animals, though we may add or remove supported animals in the future. When that happens, we'll update the minor version number of the API.”

Comment: Executable specification >>> documented specification >>> undocumented specification.

Answer (score 0):

It would only be breaking if "Rat" could be returned from existing operations.

If existing operations cannot return "Rat" then adding this new option would have no effect.